# Sub class trying to give a new value to a variable in super class

Tags: c#

```
public class superclass
    {
        public string example;
        public class subclass: superclass
        {
            public class subsubclass: subclass
            {

                public string example = "blahblah";
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to do this but I keep getting errors :

> superclass.example is a field but is used like a type

Comment: This seems to be not a good design. do you have a real world szenario where you want to do this? Typically a baseclass would define properties and a child could set this. and not vice versa

Comment: I don't see a `Name` field anywhere in your example code.

Comment: Actually, it prints a warning:`'...superclass.subclass.subsubclass.example' hides inherited member '...superclass.example'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to define the example field twice in your class hierarchy, do this:

```
public class superclass
{
    public string example;
    public class subclass: superclass
    {
        public class subsubclass: subclass
        {

            public new string example = "blahblah";
        }
    }
}
```

But what you probably want to do is this:

```
public class superclass
{
    public string example;
    public class subclass: superclass
    {
        public class subsubclass: subclass
        {
            public subsubclass()
            {
                 example = "blahblah";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first example will create a new, identical field on your subsubclass with the same type and name. I can't imagine a scenario where that makes sense. It will only lead to confusion. Imagine doing this:

```
var myObj = new subsubClass();
myObj.example = "something";
DoSomething(myObj);
```

Where DoSomething looks like this:

```
void DoSomething(superclass myObj)
{
    var tmp = myObj.example;
}
```

The above code will cause tmp to be null, not "something" as some would expect. Avoid using the new operator unless you have good cause to do so (almost never if you are coding all the classes yourself)

TL;DR: If you just want your subsubclass to set the property, do it in the constructor.

Comment: If you you already advise using the `new` modifier on a class member (field), you should perhaps also advise regarding typical dangers of doing so...

Comment: Well. I state that I can't imagine a scenario where it makes sense to override a string field with an identical one on a subclass, but I will add another word of warning. Thanks!